# php jquery get the value of each td it get on the first td

Tags: php, jquery

i have this jquery,
then i used foreach to display all the records in my database.

now im trying to do is pass the value to jquery, but the value was read only the first td.

my jquery

```
jQuery('#nannyedit').click(function(){
    jQuery('<img src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'images/jon-loader.gif', __FILE__ ); ?>" id="loading" />').appendTo("#container");
    var unanny = jQuery(this).parent().siblings("input[name=nanny]:first").val();
    var access = jQuery( 'input[name=access]' ).val();

    alert( unanny );
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo plugins_url( 'edit.php', __FILE__ ); ?>",
        data: { user_login: unanny, access: access },
        dataType: 'html',
        target: '#tab-1',
        success: function(data){
            jQuery("#container").find('img#loading').remove();
            jQuery("#container").html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

my html

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Photo</th>
        <th>Resume</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Option</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$mynanny = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM jon_nanny" );
$color1 = "#FDF7E1"; 
$color2 = "#FFFFFF"; 
$row_count = 0;
foreach ($mynanny as $nanny) {
    $mynannyphoto = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM jon_nanny_photo WHERE user_login = '".$nanny->user_login."' " );
    $mynannyresume = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM jon_nanny_resume WHERE user_login = '".$nanny->user_login."' " );
$row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_dir = ( $uploads['url'] );
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $nanny->user_login; ?></td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $nanny->email; ?></td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $nanny->fname; ?></td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $nanny->mname; ?></td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $nanny->lname; ?></td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $nanny->user_status; ?></td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $upload_dir.'/'.$mynannyphoto->imgname; ?>" width="150" />
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $upload_dir.'/'.$mynannyresume->resume; ?>" />
                <img src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'images/resume.png', __FILE__ ); ?>" />
            </a>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $nanny->date; ?></td>
            <td style="background-color:<? echo $row_color; ?>" id="getnan">
            <?php
            $url = admin_url();    
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="nanny" value="<?php echo $nanny->user_login;?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="access" value="nanny" />
            <a href="#" id="nannyedit">
                <img src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'images/edit-file-icon.png', __FILE__ ); ?>" />
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <img src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'images/delete-file-icon.png', __FILE__ ); ?>" />
            </a>
            <a href="" title="View">
                <img src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'images/Document-icon.png', __FILE__ ); ?>" />
            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php
$row_count++;
}       
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

is my jquery wrong?
please tell me thank you.

Comment: use class selector instead of id selector use `jQuery('.nannyedit').click(function(){`  instead of `jQuery('#nannyedit').click(function(){`  and also change the html `<a href="#" class="nannyedit">`

Comment: @Suchel Meman the alert value was undefined meaning its still dont get the value of the td..

Comment: @Suchel Meman thank you its working now i change just remove the .parent `jQuery(this).siblings("input[name=nanny]").val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use #nannyedit in your foreach loop.

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Change your code:

in script:

```
jQuery('.nannyedit').click(....
```

in foreach:

```
<a class='nannyedit'> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change foreach loop to while

```
 while($mynanny = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM jon_nanny" )){
```